# Absolutely positioning with flexbox in Safari

Tags: css, safari, flexbox

[Safari has full support for FlexBox according to caniuse.](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)

I am simply trying to stack some differently sized div's on top of each other using flexbox. I am genuinely curious as to why this works in Chrome/Firefox but not in Safari:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner-one"></div>
  <div class="inner-two"></div>
</div>
```

```css
.container {
  width: 15rem;
  height: 15rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: blue;

  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container div {
  position: absolute;
}

.inner-one {
  width: 13rem;
  height: 13rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: green;
}

.inner-two {
  width: 11rem;
  height: 11rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: purple;
}
```

See JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/19n95exf/3/

Comment: Have you tried with -webkit prefix?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `position: absolute;` break `display: flex`, use `transform: translate` instead

```css
    .container {
      position: relative;
      width: 15rem;
      height: 15rem;
      border-radius: 50%;
      background-color: blue;
    }

    .container div {
      border-radius: 50%;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    }

    .inner-one {
      width: 13rem;
      height: 13rem;
      background-color: green;
    }

    .inner-two {
      width: 11rem;
      height: 11rem;
      background-color: purple;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="container">
      <div class="inner-one"></div>
      <div class="inner-two"></div>
    </div>
```

---

Or give the inner elements a left/top value

```css
    .container {
      width: 15rem;
      height: 15rem;
      border-radius: 50%;
      background-color: blue;

      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
    }

    .container div {
      border-radius: 50%;
      position: absolute;
    }

    .inner-one {
      left: 1.5rem;
      top: 1.5rem;
      width: 13rem;
      height: 13rem;
      background-color: green;
    }

    .inner-two {
      left: 2.5rem;
      top: 2.5rem;
      width: 11rem;
      height: 11rem;
      background-color: purple;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="inner-one"></div>
      <div class="inner-two"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Legend. I still find it interesting that absolute is handled differently with flex in Safari. Either way this is a viable workaround. Thanks.

Comment: @AndrewHill Read this: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/06/absolute-positioned-children