# Secondary Navigation Links (Absolute and Relative positioning) (CSS)

Tags: css-position

All my secondary header navigation links can only go (top left, bottom left, top right, etc.).

Currently enabled as "top left", however I want two out of those four links to be "top right".

Current code works perfect, other than after the 75% resizing mark, the links discombobulate.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 800px)
{
    a[href="/terms-of-use"] 
    {
        position:absolute;
        right:120px;
    }

    a[href="/privacy"]
    {
        position:absolute;
        right:200px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a link to the site/page in question? If so, consider editing your question to do so. You can use a yoursite.squarespace.com/your-page URL, and provide the view-only password if necessary. That usually makes it easier to answer Squarespace-specific, CSS-related questions of this sort.

Comment: https://www.fnspreadsheets.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been said that [using absolute positioning within flex-box will not work reliably](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43780037). I'm going to guess that, because I was viewing your site in Firefox and Chrome and did not see the issue, that you are viewing your site in Safari, where the issue can be seen.

In any case, due to the above, I would recommend using Javascript in order to move the navigation items to the desired location. Then, add some additional CSS in order to get those newly-moved items to look like the others.

First, remove the CSS you've added that addresses those navigation items.

Then add this via site-wide **Footer** code injection:

```
<script>
(function() {
    var targetLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".Header a[href='/terms-of-use'], .Header a[href='/privacy']");
    var targetParent = document.querySelector(".Header-inner [data-nc-container='top-right']");
    var i;

    for (i=0; i<targetLinks.length; i++) {
        targetParent.appendChild(targetLinks[i]);
    }
})();
</script>
```

And finally, add this via the CSS Editor:

```
body:not(.tweak-header-secondary-nav-hover-style-button):not(.tweak-header-secondary-nav-inherit-styles) [data-nc-container='top-right'] .Header-nav-item {
    margin: 0 .618em;
    padding: .618em 0;
    font-family: myriad-pro;
    -webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}
[data-nc-base="header"] [data-nc-container="top-right"] [data-nc-element="cart"] {
    padding-left: 33px;
}
[data-nc-container='top-left'] [href='/privacy'] {
  display: none;
}
[data-nc-container='top-left'] [href='/terms-of-use'] {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the mobile break point for me. This doesn't solve the problem of the two links (terms of use and privacy) from being out of sync when minimized past 67% in desktop view. It's my understanding that because I'm using absolute positioning, it will not follow the natural flow when resizing the browser. I'm not sure how to create a relative container for them yet (new to CSS), but from what I've been reading that's what I need to do to keep in natural flow when resizing.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "out of sync"? Could you provide a screenshot?

Comment: the first image is at 100% ... second image 75% ... third image 50%

Comment: Great - now I believe I understand the issue. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Awesome man, thank you. For what it's worth, I was using/testing in chrome (not safari) and was getting the error. Strange that you couldn't see the issue, but regardless, this works perfectly. If you ever need spreadsheet for anything in the future i got ya.

Comment: **Sorry I didn't realize this in time, but click on any link on the home page, and the top right links duplicate on the page. Click another link, and they duplicate themselves again. I'll post a screenshot shortly

Comment: Ah, sorry about that. That has to do with AJAX loading and the first line of code within the `script`. I've updated the code and now recommend using footer code injection specifically. If that doesn't work, it's simply a matter of using `DOMContentLoaded` instead, which I can update if necessary.

Comment: It's still doing it. A link click duplicates it to the "top left" this time, but only once.

Comment: Okay - that is happening because Squarespace rewrites the nav. on every AJAX load. I've updated the CSS in the answer in order to hide those two specific nav. items on the left. You could instead use JavaScript to continually remove them, but it's certainly easiest to simply hide them.